# How to add collapsible help text to a form?

Tags: 7, forms

I would like to add some collapsible text underneath my comment forms. Preferably, users can click a small icon, which reveals the help text. After reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/8405715/2625920, I already added a paragraph at the desired position:

```
function MYTHEME_form_comment_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['markup'] = array(
    '#markup' => t('<p>Here is some very useful text.</p>'),
    '#weight' => -1,
  );
}
```

(Actually, it surprised me that this works, since `#markup` is not ticked for forms in the [Form API Reference](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7.x)...) Unfortunately, simply adding

```
'#collapsible' => TRUE,
'#collapsed' => TRUE,
```

to the array does not work (which is expected according to the Form API Reference). Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about putting it into a fieldset ?

```
$form['fieldset'] = array(
 '#title' => 'title',
 '#type' => 'fieldset',
 '#collapsible' => TRUE,
 '#description' => 'desc',
);

$form['fieldset']['some_text'] = array(
  '#markup' => '<p>Here is some very useful text.</p>',
  '#weight' => -1,
);
```